# Children of internal node in a quadtree with high dimensionality

Tags: trees, clustering

Let's say for example we have 1000 points and 50 dimensions.

And we build a quadtree where each node represents a 50-dimensional box and is divided by splitting the box into smaller boxes that are half the size in every dimension? How would i calculate how many children each internal node has?

Comment: If you are interested in high-dimensional quadtree-type indexes, have a look at my [PH-Tree](http://phtree.org). It is a somewhat optimized quadtree that works well with 50 dimensions, it was comparable to R-Tree performance for up to 1000 dimensions. 
Especially for highly clustered data (I tested with 40 dimensions) it seems to have much faster k-nearest-neighbor queries than kd-trees. The original paper (see link above) also discusses the number of subnodes in a quadtree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you split along each dimension into two parts, then in two dimensions you have $2\cdot 2 = 4$ children (that's why it's called a **quad**tree), in three dimensions you have $2\cdot 2\cdot 2 = 8$ children (that's why three-dimensional quadtrees are called [**oct**trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree)), and for $k$ dimensions you have $2^k$ children.

That's independent of the numbers of points in your tree - each internal node in a quadtree splits in the same way.

And for higher dimensions that's a lot of children, and therefore you don't want to use a quadtree in that case, but something else, for example a [k-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree).

Comment: Quadtrees can actually work quite well with 50+ dimensions if child nodes are only created when they are actually required. At least with the datasets that I tested, such a tree (called [PH-Tree](http://phtree.org) <-- self advertisement) they worked either as good (normal data) or a lot better )clustered data) than kd-trees, see [here](https://github.com/tzaeschke/TinSpin/blob/master/doc/benchmark-2017-01/Diagrams.pdf).